# Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, linux, class, command-line, command

Firstly thank you for your helps. I viewed and tried all of titles like mine but none of them help me to solve my problem. I tried this command in order to compile in current folder that includes ExampleProgram.java:

```
java -Xms16m -Xmx64m -cp ".:boilerpipe-1.2.0.jar:lib/nekohtml-1.9.13.jar:lib/xerces-2.9.1.jar:lib/langdetect.jar:lib/jsonic-1.2.8.jar" ExampleProgram.java
```

Then it gives this error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class ExampleProgram.java

This is ExampleProgram.java:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import de.l3s.boilerpipe.document.TextDocument;
import de.l3s.boilerpipe.extractors.ArticleExtractor;
import de.l3s.boilerpipe.sax.BoilerpipeSAXInput;


// Language detect librarys
import com.cybozu.labs.langdetect.*;

import net.arnx.jsonic.JSON;
import net.arnx.jsonic.JSONException;


import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.Headers;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

class ExampleProgram {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

EveryDetector evr = new EveryDetector();
InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1",8080);
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(addr, 0);

MyHandler hndl = new MyHandler();
hndl.setDetector(evr);

MyHandlerExtractContent hnd2 = new MyHandlerExtractContent();
hnd2.setDetector(evr);

MyHandlerDetectLanguage hnd3 = new MyHandlerDetectLanguage();
hnd3.setDetector(evr);

server.createContext("/",hndl);
server.createContext("/extractcontent",hnd2);
server.createContext("/detectlanguage",hnd3);
server.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
server.start();
System.out.println("Server is listening on port 8080" );


 }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/remdex/boilerpipe-and-language-detect-api-server

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: make `ExampleProgram` `public`

Comment: Thank you. I tried you said but I still facing same problem. @Ramanlfc

Answer (score 1):

Add `public` word before `class ExampleProgram` like here:

```
public class ExampleProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
```

Please remember that the main class has to be always `public`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried you said but I still facing same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change `class ExampleProgram` to `public class ExampleProgram`, as the compiler has no way of locating the class with the main method.

Note that you can only have one 'public' class, as otherwise would confuse the compiler.

Comment: Thank you. I tried you said but I still facing same problem.

Comment: @arkanas Can you post what you tried? It should most definitely work.

Comment: I changed it to public class for ExampleProgram and I entered this command: java -Xms16m -Xmx64m -cp ".:boilerpipe-1.2.0.jar:lib/nekohtml-1.9.13.jar:lib/xerces-2.9.1.jar:lib/langdetect.jar:lib/jsonic-1.2.8.jar" ExampleProgram.java

Comment: @arkanas are you running this from the command prompt? If so, make sure your directory (the path before the area where you type) contains the file you are trying to run.

Comment: Sorry, I am not good at java. Yes, I am running it from the command prompt. How can I create a directory to run this app?